# HTTPS POST with Scala and Dispatch

Tags: scala, https, scala-dispatch

I am trying to do a HTTPS post with scala and the Dispatch library. I can't find where to mark my connection as being https not http. Here is the code I have so far

```
println("Running Test")
val http = new Http
val req = :/("www.example.com" , 443) / "full/path.asp"
var response: NodeSeq = Text("")
http(req << "username=x&password=y" <> {response = _ } )
response
println("Done Running Test")
```

*EDIT*

So After attempting to figure this out I traced down what was needed the http line needs to look like this

```
http(req.secure << "username=x&password=y" <> {response = _ } )
```

Also In this specific instance I needed to POST as application/x-www-form-urlencoded that required the line to look like this

```
http(req.secure << ("username=x&password=y","application/x-www-form-urlencoded") <> {response = _ } )
```

This will now replace 40 Lines of C++ + Boost + Asio code.

Comment: I'm wondering if you'll have better luck asking this question on the Dispatch group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dispatch-scala

Comment: This will _not_ replace?

Comment: Anyway, answer your own question, please. It is a valid question, with a valid answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So After attempting to figure this out I traced down what was needed the http line needs to look like this

```
http(req.secure << "username=x&password=y" <> {response = _ } )
```

Also In this specific instance I needed to POST as application/x-www-form-urlencoded that required the line to look like this

```
http(req.secure << ("username=x&password=y","application/x-www-form-urlencoded") <> {response = _ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply "secure" to the :/ factory:

```
:/("host").secure
```